# Trigger Test Fails, Can't See Production Environment's GroupId

Tags: trigger, unit-test, sandbox, production

I have a Trigger that works in Sandbox. It posts updates to a group. So, I then hard-coded the id from the actual group in my Production environment which now causes my test to fail. I think the reason is that the sandbox can't see the id of a group in production. Can someone help me out with this test? Many Thanks.[image]

Comment: You need to query for the Id (or get it dynamically in another way), you should really never hard code an Id as they change from org to org.

Whatever the UserInfo.getUserId() is you should probably be able to get from the user that is firing your trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding IDs anywhere in apex code is not a best practice. Also record IDs are never the same in sandbox environments except full copy sandbox.

I would use the below steps to implement the above code

1. Create a custom setting to store the name of the group.

{CustomSetting Name}__c.getAll().values();

2. Get the first item of the above list to Query group id at the run time using SOQL

SELECT Id,Name From CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = :{GroupName}

Chatter group object : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm

Regarding Test Classes, use follow code to setup a new group and create a custom setting for the same name

```
public static Id createGroup(String groupName, List<User> users) {

CollaborationGroup g = new CollaborationGroup(Name=groupName, CollaborationType='Public');
g.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId() ;
insert g;

List<CollaborationGroupMember> groupMembers = new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();

for (User user: users) {
    CollaborationGroupMember member = new CollaborationGroupMember();
    member.MemberId = user.Id ;
    member.CollaborationGroupId = g.Id ;
    groupMembers.add(member);
}

insert groupMembers;
return g.Id ;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Rocket, Production and Sandbox IDs are only identical when the sandbox was refreshed after the record was created. Also, you cannot "see" records in prod from a sandbox.

There are a few other problems with your code (an insert inside of a loop is a huge no-no in Salesforce).

Focusing only in the issue at hand, you can fix your issue by querying for the group instead of hardcoding an ID.

I would write your code like this (only part of the code is added)

```
List<FeedItem> feedItemsToInsert = new List<FeedItem>();
for (weeather__c wx : trigger.new) {

  List< CollaborationGroup> group = [select Id from CollaborationGroup where name = 'MyName' limit 1];
  if (! group.isEmpty()) {
    fitem.parentid = group[0].id;
    fitem.body = 'xxxx'; //your code here

    feedItemsToInsert.add(fitem);
  }
}

insert feedItemsToInsert;
```

Comment: N.B the test for empty feedItemsToInsert is unnecessary; SFDC will execute the DML on an empty list - do nothing, and not consume a DML statement for limits purposes

Comment: Crop, feel free to edit the code so the OP can properly copy-paste it.

Comment: @Eric beat me to it. In general, I don't like to edit answers but I know I used to do those `if (!myList.isEmpty()) ...` tests until @sfdcfox pointed out they were unnecessary. So, I'm just "paying it forward" :-)

Comment: Yea, I did it when he gave permission to be done to save you some time. And I too was doing that until sfdcfox pointed out it was no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks both for your help. I was out of the house and wasn't going to be able to make the change, wanted the OP to have the best code possible. I also learned something new today! :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Assigning groupId dynamically was very helpful. Also, moving the insert outside of the For-Loop was a good addition too. But the main issue I have is writing the test. I can make the trigger do a million different things, but I'm uncertain how to test it. My test keep bombing.

Comment: Can you edit your post with The errors?